# Arangodb/Foxx how to split routes in different files?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

How could I split the routing into different files?

This what I tried, but did not work:

```
// file 'index.js' as main in manifest.json
const createRouter = require('@arangodb/foxx/router');  
const router = createRouter();
const entries = require('./routes/entries')
entries.init(router);
module.context.use("", router);
```

and the entries file is working as a function:

```
// file './routes/entries.js'
const db = require('@arangodb').db;
// [...] more const
module.exports = {
  init: function(router) {

    router.post('/entries', function(req, res) {
    // [...] post handle
    }
  }
}
```

1) How could I modify the router in a js file and reuse in?

```
module.context.use(router)
```

2) Any idea how to handle all js files in the folder 'routes' to define the router and so minimize the definition for route files?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the funtion `router.use([path], middleware, [name]): Endpoint` for that.

```
module.context.use('/entries', require('./routes/entries'), 'entries');
```

For more information take a look into the docs [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Foxx/Router/#mounting-child-routers-and-middleware) or in the newest Foxx tutorial [here](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/fine-grained-permissions) which also use child routers.

Comment: Thanks, but how about having more than one entries.js file adding to it? Can I use:

module.context.use('/entries', require('./routes/**'), 'entries');